# SQL query giving aggregate function errors even whem I am not using any

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sorry for the whole BIG query pasted below. I have gone though it over and over and over and checked places where there might be calculation errors like dividing by zero, but none works. Right now it asks me to use group by clause, like the error we get when we have a count in the select statement, and don't use a group by clause. But When I put a group by clause at the end of the query with all the columns listed out, it tells me that the column names don't exists!

Comment: I did use the aliases. did I miss any?

Comment: @stevenackley What are you talking about? You can use aliases in `ORDER BY` but not in `GROUP BY`. Did you try it?

Comment: @stevenackley It's the other way around actually. You *cannot* use column aliases in the GROUP BY, you can only use column names from your source tables (which means that you have to duplicate the expressions, in order to group on an output column value).  And actually, that's porbably the problem that the OP was having.

Comment: Can't use alias's for your groub by and you are doing an aggregation so a group by is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using sum on line 45 of your SQL:

```
(case ((sum(T.act_work_qty)+sum(T.remain_work_qty))*100.0)
        when 0 then 0
        when null then 0
        else round((sum(T.act_work_qty)/(sum(T.act_work_qty)+sum(T.remain_work_qty))*100.0),2)
    end)
```

Because of this, SQL assumes you have an aggregation query and returns an aggregation error.

Here are some ideas for workarounds . . .

1. Perhaps you don't need the sum, so you can just use the column value.
2. You can use a windows function to calculate the sum . . . `sum(T.act_work_qt) over ()` will calculate the sum over all the rows processed by the query (the `where` clause conditions are applied).
3. Use a subquery to calculate the sum.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your suggestion worked. I have updated my query in my OP by adding another temp table that does the pct calcs.
But now it breaks at some other place saying 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'!

Comment: @camelbrush . . . The solution to that is either an aggregation function or `select top 1`.

Comment: but the top1 would always return only 1 record right? Why would it say subquerry returned more than 1 value? And I tried commenting that block out, yet the same error. Can't figure out which querry is returning multiple records. I have the where clauses set up to ensure returning only the right match. :(